# SQL Query Count content in one column where equal to x or y

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one column that contains either X or Y. How can I create one query that  counts each as below?

```
Example of Input
-----------------
X
X
Y
```

Desired Output

```
CountX  |  CountY
-----------------
2       |  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(iif(input = 'X', 1, 0)) as countX,
       sum(iif(input = 'Y', 1, 0)) as countY
from your_table
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Cheers